# How to run DNNE as part of my Visual Studio project Build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I need to generate shared object files from a .NET C# project.

I have tried `Embeddinator-4000` with no luck.

I am now progressing further with its replacement `[DNNE][1]`

however I have these two build errors I cannot resolve

The first appears to be a clang error

```
/Users/user/github/my-dotnet-project/libraries/dotnet/Company.Engine/src/clang: Error: no such file or directory: '/Users/user/github/my-dotnet-project/libraries/dotnet/Company.Engine/src/obj/Debug/netstandard2.1/dnne/Brand.Company.Engine.g.c' (Company.Engine)
```

The second directly related to DNNE

```
/Users/user/.nuget/packages/dnne/1.0.32/build/DNNE.targets(5,5): Error MSB3073: The command ""clang" -g -O0 -shared -fpic -D DNNE_ASSEMBLY_NAME=Brand.Company.Engine -D DNNE_COMPILE_AS_SOURCE -I "/Users/user/.nuget/packages/dnne/1.0.32/tools/platform" -I "/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.osx-x64/6.0.9/runtimes/osx-x64/native" -o "/Users/user/github/my-dotnet-project/libraries/dotnet/Company.Engine/src/obj/Debug/netstandard2.1/dnne/bin/Brand.Company.EngineNE.dylib" "/Users/user/github/my-dotnet-project/libraries/dotnet/Company.Engine/src/obj/Debug/netstandard2.1/dnne/Brand.Company.Engine.g.c" "/Users/user/.nuget/packages/dnne/1.0.32/tools/platform/platform.c" -lstdc++ "/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.osx-x64/6.0.9/runtimes/osx-x64/native/libnethost.a" " exited with code 1. (MSB3073) (Company.Engine)
```

The version of Visual Studio I am using is as follows:-

```
Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac
Version 17.3.6 (build 20)
Installation UUID: 91c5639e-4370-4b14-a9cb-b1d754641b88

Runtime
.NET 6.0.5 (64-bit)
Architecture: X64

Roslyn (Language Service)
4.3.0-3.22312.2+52adfb8b2dc71ed4278debcf13960f2116868608

NuGet
Version: 6.2.1.2

.NET SDK (x64)
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.401/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    6.0.401
    3.1.423
MSBuild SDKs: /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MonoBundle/MSBuild/Current/bin/Sdks

.NET Runtime (x64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    6.0.9
    3.1.29

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.8.0.19
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11

Xamarin.Android
Version: 13.0.0.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/d17-3/030cd63
Android SDK: /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    Supported Android versions:
        12.1 (API level 32)
        8.0  (API level 26)
        12.0 (API level 31)
        8.1  (API level 27)
        5.0  (API level 21)
        11.0 (API level 30)
        10.0 (API level 29)
        9.0  (API level 28)
        13.0 (API level 33)
        7.0  (API level 24)

SDK Command-line Tools Version: 7.0
SDK Platform Tools Version: 33.0.3
SDK Build Tools Version: 33.0.0 rc2

Build Information: 
Mono: dffa5ab
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d17-3@7716ae53
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.38.5@df4deab
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/main@14076a6

Microsoft Build of OpenJDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-11.jdk
11.0.12
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Eclipse Temurin JDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk
1.8.0.302
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Android SDK Manager
Version: 17.3.0.23
Hash: 965bf40
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-3
Build date: 2022-09-22 15:23:52 UTC

Android Device Manager
Version: 0.0.0.1169
Hash: fafb1d5
Branch: fafb1d5
Build date: 2022-09-22 15:23:52 UTC

Apple Developer Tools
A valid Xcode installation was not found at the configured location: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'

Xamarin.Mac
Xamarin.Mac not installed. Can't find /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/Version.

Xamarin.iOS
Xamarin.iOS not installed.
Can't find mtouch or the Version file at /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current.

Xamarin Designer
Version: 17.3.0.208
Hash: 0de472ea0
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-3
Build date: 2022-09-22 15:23:48 UTC

Build Information
Release ID: 1703060020
Git revision: f7a6334599543f127e737d6de1f362bbe36cebca
Build date: 2022-09-22 15:21:08+00
Build branch: release-17.3
Build lane: release-17.3

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.15.7
Darwin 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0
    Tue Nov 10 00:10:30 PST 2020
    root:xnu-6153.141.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Enabled user installed extensions
NuGet Package Explorer 0.10
NuGet Package Management Extensions 0.31
```

how can i resolve these two build errors?

Is the issue that DNNE only works on "`.c`" files NOT `c#`?